# Where does Perl for Windows look when a script has a default directory like /usr/games/lib?

Tags: windows, perl, directory

I am trying to set up [Text::FIGlet](http://search.cpan.org/~jpierce/Text-FIGlet-2.18/lib/Text/FIGlet.pm) on Windows.

By default it looks for fonts stored in /usr/games/lib/figlet. Where would this be on Windows?

I thought maybe if I put the structure /usr/games/lib/figlet under C that would do the trick, but it doesn't.

The reason I want to get the default folder working is so I don't have to manually set the font directory every time I use Figlet.

Thanks

Comment: Perl "looks" exactly where told. If it's told to "look" in /usr/games/lib/figlet, it will look in /usr/games/lib/figlet. Being a relative path, the current work drive will be used. That's all handled by the OS itself.

Comment: Ah, current work drive. I was running the script from another drive. I wrongly thought it would look on the drive the perl executable was located. I put /usr/games/lib/figlet on the same drive as the script and all is good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, it defaults to that location, but that is a Unix-like location. Path separators aside, that directory structure is unlikely to be found on a windows system. Use that switch to point to the directory on your system which contains the needed files (i.e. `c:\path\to\files`).

Comment: (Windows recognizes `/` as a path separator. Perl doesn't translate `/` to `\ `; when you pass `/` to Perl, you pass `/` to Windows.)

Comment: I defer to ikegami on Windows/Perl handling of path separators. Just as a clarification (as I hope I have conveyed), that path is likely to be correct on Linux (i.e already exist) and unlikely to be correct on windows; rather than build the directory structure to match the linux default, why not just point to the correct one for windows.